# How can an SN1 reaction give non-racemic products?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereoselectivity

I'm in organic 1 right now and we assume that SN1 reaction will always have racemic products for the sake of simplicity. But then our professor have a question for us that these solvolysis reactions will not end up with racemic products. Could you help me find the reason why it is not racemization?

[image: Nucleophilic substitution that will result in non-racemic products]

Comment: Please use Stack Exchange image hosting service for uploading images. Press the little image pictogram above the text box in the editor and upload. The image will be uploaded to a dedicated webspace which is guaranteed to remain existant. (Note that you should not upload copyrighted work.)

Comment: The assumption SN1 -> racemic is a useful concept, but the reaction does not have to proceed by SN1 only. Further, consider that the lifetime of certain carbocations may be long enough for geometry changes to more favorable conformations that may have preferred attack paths.

Comment: Look up conformations of substituted t-butyl cyclohexanes to get a clue. For the 2nd, find a neighbouring part of the molecule that could "participate"